# Discord.py Getting a bot to add role based on csv file

Tags: python, discord.py, roles, csvreader

So I am new to Python, Discord.py, and programming in general, but I am using Discord as a good opportunity to learn. So please excuse any illiteracy on my part.

I have assembled a bot from bits and pieces here and there on the Internet, and it’s working as intended. But I am now stumped when trying to add a specific function.

For context, the Discord server I am an admin of is a video game publishing server, so we use it for beta test and feedback collection. For an upcoming beta test, we would like to automatically add a "beta-test" role to a list of users (a .csv file), that will give them access to specific channels and commands.

The issue is with the file reading part. I can get the bot from opening the .csv file and printing or sending its content to a specific channel BUT it does not recognize any printed name as a server member.

So first, here is the code:

```
discord.Intents.default()


@bot.command(name='addrole', hidden=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add_beta_role(ctx, role='beta-test'):
    with open('./beta_list.csv', 'r+') as beta_role_file:
        for item in beta_role_file:
            print(f'{item}')

            guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == ctx.guild, bot.guilds)
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == item, ctx.guild.members)

            if role is not None:
                if member is not None:
                    await member.add_roles()
                    print(f'{role} added to {member}')
                
                else:
                    print(f'Member not found.')
            else:
                print(f'Role not found.')
```

The .csv file that I use contains 4 lines, for 4 different users, with differently formatted names:

1. Discord name + discriminator (eg: User#123, real user in the server)
2. Discord name (eg: User, real username in the server)
3. Non-existing user (to make sure the bot picks up an anomaly)
4. Discord ID (eg: 123456789, real user ID in the server)

The output I have is:

```
User1
Member not found.

User2
Member not found.

User3
Member not found.

User4
Member not found.
```

I would like the bot to be able to find the server members based on the list of users in the .csv file, but it does not work. I have tried to modify the code so that the bot would first send the list to a Discord channel and then use the message content to find the Discord members, but I have had no better luck.

If anyone could point out how to do it or where the issue lies, I would be very grateful

*edit: edited for clarity*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just iterate over a csv file to get the items.
Python has a great built-in [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html) to do that.

```
import csv
with open('./beta_list.csv', 'r+') as beta_role_file:
    reader = csv.reader(beta_role_file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Adapt this code with your csv file

Comment: Oh! I tried with the csv.reader() before, but the output looked like ['User1'], which made me think was the reason I could not match the csv file users with their Discord counterparts. So, if I use the csv.reader(), I still get the same output:

`['User1']
Member not found`

Is the issue stemming from the fact that I cannot do the row/member match correctly in my code?

Comment: @IIIAzraeLIII Try with row[0]